# Request object is empty in a lumen api

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, api, lumen

Uploading the image file in lumen API using ajax call, it not getting the image in the lumen for processing, the Request object is empty.

**Ajax call**

```
var file = $('#img')[0].files[0];
var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("myform"));
form_data.append("img", file);

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8000/api/image",
    type: "POST",
    data: form_data,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
})
.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

**Route**

```
$api->post('/image', 'ImagesController@addImage');
```

**Controller**

```
public function addImage(Request $request) {
    return $request; // returns empty object
}
```

[Request payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYqyl.jpg)

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1ZUW.jpg)

Comment: Did you managed to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

In your controller add this line

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Do not use the `Request` facade as Lumen works differently from Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a JavaScript object this way, this will ensure passing the body to the request.

```
let form_data = {
      'name': $('#name').value(),
      'file': $('#img')[0].files[0]
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8000/api/image",
      type: "POST",
      data: form_data,
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
      contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    })
    .done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
```